Forgot my password on Technitium
I have forgotten my password and Technitium, and its instructions are not quite clear (Start the DNS Server to complete the password reset process., precisely). Furthermore, I have tried uninstalling and installing Technitium again via the official instruction, but it has also failed. What procedure shall I go through?

The two close votes on this question for not an official Ubuntu flavor seem dubious to me.

@karel. This is software running on a raspberry. Yes, generally debian but Technitium does run on Ubuntu.

Uninstalling and reinstalling usually do not reset the password because the config files remain on your system. First stop Technitium service.  In Ubuntu, you can stop it via:
sudo systemctl stop technitium-dns.service

Then you can use the Technitium binary to reset the password:
sudo ./TechnitiumDNS --reset-password


The first command lead to an error. Failed to stop technitium-dns.service: Unit technitium-dns.service not loaded.

we ONLY support Ubuntu. Windows instructions have nothing to do in an answer

With a RUNNING service you can do:
TOKEN=$(curl -s "http://{IP}:{PORT}/api/user/login?user=admin&pass=admin&includeInfo=true" | jq -r '.token')
curl "http://{IP}:{PORT}/api/user/changePassword?token=$TOKEN&pass=PASS"

where PASS is the new password. (ip is likely localhost or ip and port are what you used during setup) (if unsure: 3000 or 5380 are in the manual).
The method where the service is stopped (dns.service is the name they used in their installer so I would assume this is the one you need):
sudo systemctl stop dns.service
sudo mv /etc/dns/config/auth.config /etc/dns/config/resetadmin.config
sudo systemctl start dns.service

The open a browser with the IP adres and port 3000 with /dns
http://{IP}:{PORT}/dns

(ip is likely localhost or ip and port are what you used during setup) and you will be prompted for a new password.
